# Scheme Function checking balanced parenthesis

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to check for balanced parenthesis in scheme with a string as given input but what I have is not working correctly and I do not know why. Any insight on what I need to change? Thanks.

```
(define (balanced? st)
  (define lst (string->list st))
  (display lst)
  (if (equal? (string-length st) 0)
      #t
      (counter lst 0)
  ))

(define (counter lst count)

  (cond
    ((and (= count 0) (= (length lst) 0) #t))
    ((and (not(= count 0)) (= (length lst) 0) #f))
    ((equal?  (first lst) "(") (counter (cdr lst) (+ count 1)))
    ((equal? (first lst) ")") (counter (cdr lst) (- count 1)))
    (counter (cdr lst) count)
  )
)
```

Comment: Note that you can collapse the first two clauses to `((empty? lst) (= count 0))`. (There is almost never a need to compute the length of a list.)

Answer (score 0):

The last clause of `cond` needs `else` as the condition.

```
(define (counter lst count)

  (cond
    ((and (= count 0) (= (length lst) 0) #t))
    ((and (not(= count 0)) (= (length lst) 0) #f))
    ((equal?  (first lst) "(") (counter (cdr lst) (+ count 1)))
    ((equal? (first lst) ")") (counter (cdr lst) (- count 1)))
    (else (counter (cdr lst) count))
  )
)
```

Your code has `counter` as the last condition, then it calls `(cdr lst)` and discards the value, and returns `count`.

Comment: It's `else`, not `#else` :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version, tested in mit-scheme:

```
(define balanced
  (lambda (input break ret)
    (if (null? input)
        (ret 'eos)
        (if (char=? (car input) #\()
            (balanced
             (cdr input)
             break
             (lambda (rest)
               (assert
                (or (eq? rest 'eos)
                    (char=? #\) (car rest))))
               (if (eq? rest 'eos)
                   (break)
                   (balanced (cdr rest) break ret))))
            (if (char=? (car input) #\))
                (ret input)
                (balanced (cdr input) break ret))))))
```

Here is an unit test:

```
(define test
  (lambda (input)
    (display input)
    (display " => ")
    (balanced
     (string->list input)
     (lambda ()
       (display "error"))
     (lambda (rest)
       (display (if (eq? rest 'eos) "OK" "error"))))
    (newline)))
```

Input test:

```
(test "(")
(test ")")
(test "()")
(test "((")
(test "))")
(test ")(")
(test "(abc)")
(test "(a(b)c)")
(test "(")
(test ")")
(test "(a)b)")
(test "(a(b)")
(test "(a(b)c))(")
(test "(a(b)c)()")
```

> ```
> % mit-scheme --silent < balanced.scm
> ( => error
> ) => error
> () => OK
> (( => error
> )) => error
> )( => error
> (abc) => OK
> (a(b)c) => OK
> ( => error
> ) => error
> (a)b) => error
> (a(b) => error
> (a(b)c))( => error
> (a(b)c)() => OK
> ```